# Looking for a .NET library to do authentication that support multiple sources

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership, membership

I'm looking for a suggestion for a .NET library which can allow me to use in an ASP.NET application so that I have one profile for each user, but can associate authentication from multiple sources including: ASP.NET Forms based, windows live id, google, facebook, openid, etc...
I want people to come to my website and be able to associate any of those credentials so that they can use one or more sources to authenicate themselves.
I'm asking specifically for an ASP.NET MVC project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dotnetopenauth is a good option for multiple openid logins http://www.dotnetopenauth.net/

Answer (score 2):

Andrew,

You may have a difficult time finding one (free), single library that interfaces with all of the providers that mentioned. Check out something like the [Altairis Id Tool kit](http://www.codeplex.com/AltairisIdToolkit) on  [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com) and see if you can use that. Otherwise,  I think your best bet would be to build on top of the existing Asp.Net membership provider model and then check out [Codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com) for the different providers that you want to plug in.

Here are some suggestions...

[openid](http://www.codeplex.com/OpenIDMembership)

[facebook](http://www.codeplex.com/FacebookNET)

[google](http://www.codeplex.com/AltairisIdToolkit)