# ASP.NET MVC 3 and authentication support from multiple sources

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to know what's the best way to deal with authentication in Asp.NET MVC 3 from multiple sources like :

- custom Form authentication social
- networking (Facebook, twitter, etc.)
- other ?

I found this link : [Looking for a .NET library to do authentication that support multiple sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494026/looking-for-a-net-library-to-do-authentication-that-support-multiple-sources) but would like to be sure if there is some more means to make authentication since that question was asked.

I don't want to be tightly coupled to one specific provider so maybe I should write some wrapper around it, but if you have some guidance, it could be nice to hear from your experience.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popular social networking sites (such as Facebook and Twitter) implement the OpenID functionality; and you can your own authentication to use OpenID. You could implement your own OpenID Membership Provider.

On a side note, it means you could authenticate users on StackOverflow too!

Let me know if I can help.

Matt

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351)

Comment: +1 I'm going to do more research on this as it looks very interesting. Have you used it yourself?